# SQLITE: How to select a column value based on different columns in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I apologise in advance because I have no idea how to structure this question.
I have the following tables:

```
Sessions:
+----------+---------+
| login    | host    |
+----------+---------+
| breilly  | node001 |
+----------+---------+
| pparker  | node003 |
+----------+---------+
| jjameson | node004 |
+----------+---------+
| jjameson | node012 |
+----------+---------+

Userlist:
+----------+----------------+------------------+
| login    | primary_server | secondary_server |
+----------+----------------+------------------+
| breilly  | node001        | node010          |
+----------+----------------+------------------+
| pparker  | node002        | node003          |
+----------+----------------+------------------+
| jjameson | node003        | node004          |
+----------+----------------+------------------+
```

What kind of SQL query should I perform so I can get a table like this?:

```
+----------+---------+------------+
| login    | Host    | Server     |
+----------+---------+------------+
| jjameson | node004 | Secondary  |
+----------+---------+------------+
| jjameson | node012 | Wrong Node |
+----------+---------+------------+
| pparker  | node003 | Secondary  |
+----------+---------+------------+
| breilly  | node001 | Primary    |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

Currently I'm just using Go with a bunch of structs / hashmaps to generate this.
I am planning to migrate the users / sessions to an in memory `sqlite` Database, but I can't seem to wrap my head around a query to get this sort of table.

The `Server` column is based on whether the user is logged on his primary / secondary or wrong machine.

I've put this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8b032/1) as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` logic:

```
select s.*,
       (case when s.host = ul.primary_server then 'primary'
             when s.host = ul.secondary_server then 'secondary'
             else 'wrong node'
        end) as server
from sessions s left join
     userlist ul
     on s.login = ul.login;
```

Comment: You're a star... then I saw your credentials and realised you're a god ... I knew it had something to do with CASE but couldn't figure it out. 
If you don't mind, can I know what would be a better way to ask this question?

Comment: @mindrunner . . . Your question is reasonable.  In particular, you have sample data and desired results, so it is pretty easy to see the logic you want to implement.

Comment: thanks again @gordon-linoff This will add tons of power into my daily scripting / analysis routines. Cheers.